# ASG with ELB healthcheck is not replacing instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

According to the [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/healthcheck.html), an ASG can be set to use an ELB to determine the health status of its instances.

> If you have attached a load balancer to your Auto Scaling group, you
>   can optionally have Auto Scaling include the results of Elastic Load
>   Balancing health checks when determining the health status of an
>   instance. After you add these health checks, Auto Scaling also marks
>   an instance as unhealthy if Elastic Load Balancing reports the
>   instance state as OutOfService. For more information, see Adding
>   Health Checks to Your Auto Scaling Group.

I have an ASG with one instance with the healthcheck set to ELB. The ASG sizes are set to Desired 1, Min 0, Max 2. The healthcheck grace period is 0. I've configured the instance to fail the healthcheck on purpose so the ELB has marked the instance as unhealthy but the ASG will not replace the instance. It still marks it as in service. What am I missing?

Comment: Do you set the Desired value manually?

Comment: What health check did you set?

Comment: @error2007s The ASG is using the ELB for its healthcheck. It points to a page that returns a 500.

Comment: @Mahdi It started with 1 by default. There are no scaling policies attached.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?